# Elliptic curve n-torsion point?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

> For an elliptic curve $E/k$, let $\alpha$ be any endomorphism over
>   $\bar{k}$ in End($E$) and let $[n]$ be the multiplication-by-n
>   endomorphism. Show that for any n-torsion point $P \in E[n]$, we must
>   have $\alpha(P) \in E[n]$.

I know and have just showed that $[n]$ is commutative with all endomorphisms but I'm not sure how to use that fact here. What's a good way to show $\alpha(P) \in E[n]$?

Comment: In general, if two endomorphims commute, each stabilizes the kernel of the other.

Comment: @CaptainLama how exactly does that help here?

Comment: Well, you say you showed that $[n]$ commutes with all $\alpha$ and you want to prove that $\alpha$ stabilizes the kernel of $[n]$.